# How are these equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How are both sides of these equations equal to one another?

$(\sqrt[4]{x}-\sqrt[4]{y})\cdot(\sqrt{x^{3}}+\sqrt{y^{3}})\cdot\frac{\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y}}{x-\sqrt{xy}+y}=
(\sqrt[4]{x}-\sqrt[4]{y})\cdot(\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y})\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^{3}}+\sqrt{y^{3}}}{x-\sqrt{xy}+y}$

I copied this verbatim from a calculus study guide (I'm trying to teach myself), and I'm confused as to how $(\sqrt{x^{3}}+\sqrt{y^{3}})$ switches places with $\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y}$

Comment: $$\small\left(\sqrt[4]{x}-\sqrt[4]{y}\right)\cdot\left(\color{green} {                 \sqrt{x^{3}}+          
 \sqrt{ {y^{3}} { {}  {} {} {} {}  }  } }               \right)\cdot                    \frac{\color{#C00}{\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y}}}{x-\sqrt{xy}+y}                   = 
        \left(\sqrt[4]{x}-\sqrt[4]{y}\right)     \cdot\left(\color{#C00}{\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y}}\right)\cdot\frac{\color{green}{\sqrt{x^{3}}+\sqrt{y^{3}}}}{x-\sqrt{xy}+y}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$(\sqrt[4]{x}-\sqrt[4]{y})\cdot(\sqrt{x^{3}}+\sqrt{y^{3}})\cdot\frac{\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y}}{x-\sqrt{xy}+y}=
(\sqrt[4]{x}-\sqrt[4]{y})\cdot(\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y})\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^{3}}+\sqrt{y^{3}}}{x-\sqrt{xy}+y}$

The $\sqrt{x^{3}}+\sqrt{y^{3}}$ and$\sqrt[4]{x}+\sqrt[4]{y}$ are swapped. That's all.

$$a\times\frac{b}{c}=b\times\frac{a}{c}$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $a\cdot\frac{b}{c}=b\cdot\frac{a}{c}$